# Where is the recent activity link?

Tags: support, user-interface

I'm only linked to https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/330777 when there is a new comment, isn't there a link to this page from some other location?
I've often looked for this log as soon as I notice my score was changed, to see what question it was that made it go up/down. But I failed to find a link on my profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the envelope next to your name at the top of every page.

Comment: now I feel stupid, but I also feel that this list would be accessible somewhere around profile -> activity